# How to group 2 edits on GitHub as 1 pull request?

Tags: git, github

I have two GitHub profiles (one for work and one for personal), and sometimes I'd fork a repo on GitHub, and edit it right on GitHub to send a pull request.  This works for just one file: I can edit one file and then commit the change, and create a pull request.

But what if I need to edit two files?  One will show up as `patch-5` in my forked repo, and another one as `patch-6` in my repo, and I can't "group" them together for a pull request.  I tried to use a pull request from patch-5 to patch-6 and have it merged, and then send a pull request from patch-6, but it still show only one file for the pull request to the original source.  How can it be done?

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend to do this from CLI. Otherwise you can create a PR of one patch to the other, merge it with “squash and merge” and then do a unique PR to the branch where you want to put edits.

AFAIK there’s no other way to do so, directly from GitHub.